# Was Miss Beadle the inspiration for Clara Clayton in BttF3?

Tags: character, back-to-the-future-part-3

Watching "Back to the Future III", I realized that Clara Clayton - the schoolteacher that Doc Brown falls head-over-heels for, is a dead-ringer for Miss Beadle, the schoolteacher for much of "Little House on the Prairie". The two women share the same profession, the same style of dress, the same kind of personality, roughly the same hairstyle, an interest in science as a hobby - the two actresses even look like they could be sisters.

[image]

Obviously, "Little House on the Prairie" predates BttF by over a decade, and was considered by many to be a popular take on life in the Old West. This left me wondering if maybe the similarities between the two schoolteachers wasn't a coincidence.

**Has anyone involved with the production of "Back to the Future III" commented on the similarities between these two characters, or on the inspiration for the Clara Clayton character?**